# Who are the fathers of the chicks at the end of Chicken Run?

Tags: plot-explanation, chicken-run

At the end of the film the chickens are on an island bird refuge, along with their chicks. Rocky is romantically involved with Ginger, and Fowler is presumably to old to procreate (otherwise, why was he kept in the chicken farm). No other roosters are shown. Who sired the chicks?

Comment: In the words of Dr. Ian Malcolm: "Life, uh... finds... uh... a way."

Comment: @Tim - at least with chickens you don't get 'the running & the screaming'... ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Depends on the chicken. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAhB4JMjT7w

Answer (score 6):

**We don't know.**

Given the evidence there are 2 possible answers:

1: Rocky; the only known rooster on the island.

2: Some other, unnamed, wild rooster who is capable of flying or swimming to the island.

Honestly the likely intention of the writers to include chicks on the island was meant to indicate how safe and prosperous the chickens where in their new home. I doubt any though was put into 'Where did these chicks come from?'